# Finding the key by playing a scale

Tags: scales, key

I have a hard time finding the the key that a song is in, so I tried something different.  While the song is playing a I played a pentatonic scale in different keys until I found one that sounded right. It seems to work, but I'm curious if others find this to be an easy way to find the key ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The two missing notes from a full diatonic major scale to a pent. major are the two which are important in the V7 chord. So when the song is at that V7 chord, the pent. notes won't be a good fit to anything. So, to me it's a bit of a red herring. Also, there are the major *and* minor pents, which could prove to be misleading.

However, if it works for you, well and good. For me, just listening to the bass line, and getting to a cadence that feels it's come home is enough - more often than not, it's a perfect cadence (V>I) and that gives the I point where the root of the key will be obvious.

If all else fails, assuming there's no key change or modulation, the last chord will 99% of the time be the key chord - providing, of course, that the song doesn't fade out...